# PythonShellError: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in electron

Tags: python, electron

I try to do ocr on an image. When I execute this in python shell , it's work fine.but When it is from electron with node module python-shell I go this message.

```
PythonShellError: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
    at PythonShell.parseError 
    '    result = "-"+pytesseract.image_to_string(Unsplashinput_img[w:x,y:z]
```

sources python

```
import cv2
import math
from scipy import ndimage
import pytesseract
import sys


w=361
x=388
y=433
z=921

w1=17
x1=61
y2=316
z2=544
IMAGE_FILE_LOCATION = '/test1.png' #param1 file_name
Unsplashinput_img = cv2.imread(IMAGE_FILE_LOCATION) 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe' 
result = "-"+pytesseract.image_to_string(Unsplashinput_img[w:x,y:z] )
result +="-"+pytesseract.image_to_string(Unsplashinput_img[w1:x1,y2:z2])

print(result)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Checking this should be easy: `print(Unsplashinput_img)`.  The error message suggests that this is `None`; you claim it isn't.  We can't do much more to help, since you haven't provided the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok i'll add the electon script

Answer (score 0):

You file is not found, so your `Unsplashinput_img` is None.

The error tells you that you cannot index it (with `[w:x,y:z]` for example) since it is not an array.

You maybe missed a dot in `'/test1.png'` -> `'./test1.png'`

Comment: I don't ,the path is correct , I Have check several times

Comment: @MaikolAhoue So what does it tell you when you `print(Unsplashinput_img)` ? If None, then the path is incorrect. Try an absolute path. Also you seem to pass a Unix path format while on Windows.